Plotting a nonlinear function in R
I am currently struggling to plot the next function in R.
(F1 / F2^m * (R1 - F1)^((1 - s) / s)) - (m * (((R1 - F1))^(1 / s) + ((R2 - F2))^(1 / s)) / (F1^m + F2^m)) = 0
Where I want to plot F2 as a function of F1. That is, F2 in y-axis and F1 in the x-axis. The values R1,R2 are fixed constants and s,m are also fixed.
As the function is non-linear, I was suggested to use a numeric approximation to find the values of F2 in a domain of F1 previously defined.
I developed the next code defining first the constants, then the function, and the root finding function as:
rm(list=ls())

library(ggplot2)

R1_values <- c(100)  # Example values for R1
R2_values <- c(100)  # Example values for R2
s_values <- c(1)  # Example values for s
m_values <- c(1)  # Example values for m

# Define the original function to solve for F2
F2_function <- function(F1, F2, R1, R2, s, m) {
  (F1 / F2^m * (R1 - F1)^((1 - s) / s)) - (m * (((R1 - F1))^(1 / s) + ((R2 - F2))^(1 / s)) / (F1^m + F2^m))
}


F1_values <- seq(0.01, 100, by = 0.1)
# Solve for F2
F2_values <- sapply(F1_values, function(F1) {
  tryCatch({
    # 
    uniroot(F2_function, c(0.01, 100), F1 = F1, R1 = R1, R2 = R2, s = s, m = m, tol = 1e-8)$root
  }, error = function(e) NA)
})

data <- data.frame(F1 = F1_values, F2 = F2_values)

ggplot(data, aes(x = F1, y = F2)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "F2 as a Function of F1",
       x = "F1",
       y = "F2") +
  theme_minimal()

Everything however, returns a NA or extremly large values (randomly knowing when or how). Even when the function is clearly defined in other software (Geogebra) picture attached.

Hence, I would like to ask help of how to do the plot (and recover the values of F2 for each part of the domain of F1).
The equation in mathematical terms looks like:

PD: I think F2 has two results for each F1, but I am also unable to sort this out.

It would help to know the values of m,s,R1 & R2. Your equation seems to have a few too many brackets in which doesn't help readability. Also is s an odd integer? (so that real roots of x^(1/s) exist)

Hi @MartinBrown I am setting m=1, s=1, and R1= 100 along with R2=100. I let them in the code as R1_values <- c(100) , R2_values <- c(100) . s_values <- c(1), m_values <- c(1).
so m=s=1 and R1=R2=100.
I used the parenthesis to avoid problems... but I am open to potential fixes

I suspect the problem here is incorrect rearrangement of the equation to produce a F2 = f(F1)  form

Thanks @CarlWitthoft I think an analytical solution of the form F2=f(F1) is not plausible due to the non-separability of F2 and F1. That's why I was suggestd to use nummerical methods instead... but I think the function has two images in F2 for every F1

We can solve this explicitly using Ryacas0.  Note that there are two roots
and that the argument of sqrt is negative if F1 > 50 so using 50 as the
upper bound instead of 100 and plotting the two roots (positive root is black)
we have:
library(Ryacas0)

m <- s <- 1
R1 <- R2 <- 100
F1 <- Sym("F1")
F2 <- Sym("F2")
z <- (F1 / F2^m * (R1 - F1)^((1 - s) / s)) -
  (m * (((R1 - F1))^(1 / s) + ((R2 - F2))^(1 / s)) / (F1^m + F2^m))
zs <- Simplify(z)
F2solve <- Solve(zs, F2)
F2solve
## Yacas vector:
## [1] F2 == (200 - 2 * F1 + sqrt((2 * F1 - 200)^2 - 4 * F1^2))/2
## [2] F2 == (200 - 2 * F1 - sqrt((2 * F1 - 200)^2 - 4 * F1^2))/2

f1 <- seq(0.1, 50, .1)
f2p <- (200 - 2 * f1 + sqrt((2 * f1 - 200)^2 - 4 * f1^2))/2
f2m <- (200 - 2 * f1 - sqrt((2 * f1 - 200)^2 - 4 * f1^2))/2

matplot(f1, cbind(f2p, f2m))



@Gabor G:  is there a README or some such which explains the difference between  Ryacas0 and Ryacas packages?

This solution is simply perfect. I asked quite a lot over different forums, and definitely this was the best. I was trying different specifications instead of a single analytical solution. No good results I obtained. by arriving to the conclusion that F1 has two images on F2 this partially explain the abnormal results I had. I truly appreciate this.

@Carl Witthoft, Ryacas is a later version of Ryacas0.  Check the Ryacas NEWS file.
